# Python Selenium Wait not working / Java Selenium Question

Tags: python, selenium

I am having an issue and for the life of me I cannot figure out why it wouldn't be working especially since the usage should be very straightforward. I cannot get any of the waits to work in Selenium at all. Both implicit and explicit waits simply do not work and I have no clue why.

Here's my code:

```
from os import times
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
import json
from dataclasses import dataclass, asdict
import time

USER_NAME = "username"
PASSWORD = "password"


options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()

options.add_argument('--igcognito')
#options.add_argument('--headless')

driver = webdriver.Chrome('c:\\path\\to\\chromedriver.exe',options=options)


driver.get("URL")



driver.find_element_by_name("username").send_keys(USER_NAME)

driver.find_element_by_name("password").send_keys(PASSWORD)

driver.find_element_by_xpath("/html/body/div/div/div/div[2]/div[2]/form/button").click()

driver.get("URL")

driver.implicitly_wait(30)


expansion_buttons = driver.find_elements_by_class_name("class-control")

print(len(expansion_buttons))

for x in range(len(expansion_buttons)):
    driver.execute_script("arguments[0].click();", expansion_buttons[x])

#time.sleep(120)
#driver.implicitly_wait(60)
try:

    wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 120)
    wait.until(expected_conditions.visibility_of_all_elements_located((By.CLASS_NAME, "stuff")))
finally:
   # driver.quit()
    pass

vehicles_classes = driver.find_elements_by_class_name("stuff")

print(len(vehicles_classes))
```

Comment: Is your question about Java or Python? It should be either one, not both, or the question may be closed.

Comment: Python really and the issue with the explicit and implicit wait.

Comment: Where do you get exception?

Comment: I think I actually figured this out. I misunderstood how the wait was implemented. Additionally, the explicit wait doesn't seem to work if the elements aren't listed in the DOM to begin with. Basically, I have buttons which are clicked and expanded and then additional data populates the page. But the elements which contain this data don't exist I believe until the button is actually clicked.

Now if I can only find out why my xPath works in Python but not in Java.

Comment: Was your question answered? If so, accept it.

Answer (score 0):

1 Try not to mix implicit and explicit waits. It can lead to unpredictable wait periods. Check here for more info

2 If you select using strictly implicit waits, then declare it in the beginning. like this:

```
from os import times
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
import json
from dataclasses import dataclass, asdict
import time

USER_NAME = "username"
PASSWORD = "password"
options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()

options.add_argument('--igcognito')
#options.add_argument('--headless')

driver = webdriver.Chrome('c:\\path\\to\\chromedriver.exe',options=options)
driver.implicitly_wait(30)  # Declare here!    
driver.get("URL")


driver.find_element_by_name("username").send_keys(USER_NAME)
driver.find_element_by_name("password").send_keys(PASSWORD)
```

3 Your explicit wait:

```
wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 120)
wait.until(expected_conditions.visibility_of_all_elements_located((By.CLASS_NAME, "stuff")))
```

It looks correct, however it's not clear why you are using try/finally here. You do not really need it in context of waiting, unless there is some exact reason. `120` - is too long. Reduce wait time.

4 `driver.find_element_by_xpath("/html/body/div/div/div/div[2]/div[2]/form/button").click()` seems like a very unstable XPath. I suggest you to learn about `XPath` and `css` selectors. They should be unique if you are working with a single element.

5 I strongly suggest using only explicit waits. Check here how to use them correctly https://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/waits.html#explicit-waits

General suggestion: start from a little. Open a site and then check each action incrementally. Do not try to automate everything at once. It will be very difficult for you as for beginner.